# Why Lorentzian momentum corresponds to $1/$length?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, interactions

I'm reading Peskin & Schroeder's QFT, the effective coupling related with QED, is given by (7.96):
\begin{align}
\alpha_{\rm eff}(q^2)=\frac{\alpha}{1-\frac{\alpha}{3\pi}\log \left( \frac{-q^2}{Am^2}\right)},\tag{7.96}
\end{align}
where $\alpha\simeq 1/137$, $A={\rm exp}(5/3)$. They claim that we can write this coupling as a function of $r$ by setting $q=1/r$, and they say that this $r$-dependence comes from vacuum polarization and screening. My question is the following. I think that squared-Lorentzian momentum $q^2$ does not necessarily represent the strength or scale of energy, but rather the Wick rotated one, $q_E^2$ corresponds to it. And I think he does too. Because if you don't Wick rotate, the contents of $\log$ will not be positive definite. Am I right? And do P&S also do so implicitly just by not writing it explicitly?